# Custom validation with three textboxs

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net, validation

I have three textboxes in my asp.net application, i.e, textbox1,textbox2, textbox3. My problem is that either I have to fill textbox1 and textbox2 both or textbox3. How can I use Custom Validator?

Any clue

Partha

Comment: you may do your test on form submit event

Answer (score 0):

Here is small javascript code which you can use:

```
function Validate(){
 var textbox1= document.getElementById("textbox1").value;
 var textbox2= document.getElementById("textbox2").value;
 var textbox3= document.getElementById("textbox3").value;
 if (textbox1 && textbox2){
    return true;
 }
 else if(textbox3){
     return true;
 }

 return false;
}
```

You can call this method on submit of your form and then accordingly show the validation error message.